# TVirtualStringTree change cursor when hoverering an image

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

How can I change the cursor when I'm hovering an ImageIndex from a node

Basically I have an attach icon displayed on a node and i would like to let user understand, by changing the cursor, that he have the possibility to download the file by pressing on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tree's `OnMouseMove` event check wether the cursor is over the "icon area" and change the cursor accordingly. Something like

```
procedure TForm1.VTMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var HitInfo: THitInfo;
begin
  VT.GetHitTestInfoAt(X, Y, True, HitInfo);
  if(hiOnNormalIcon in HitInfo.HitPositions)then begin
     VT.Cursor := crHandPoint;
  end else begin
     VT.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
end;
```

The `VT` variable is your TVirtualStringTree object.